# How do I send SMS through my own server/service?

Tags: text, service, sms, message

How do companies like twilio or textfree or textnow or burner app etc send texts? If i purchase my own number from a service like signalwire, how could I finally be free from either porting my signalwire to another service and be stuck at their WHIM?

I want to port numbers I purchase from signalwire to my own service just like companies like twilio have or text sending apps, and manage my own service.

Note, I am not a developer at all.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

All of those companies are probably connected to Telco network, directly or indirectly. That means physical network operator. At that point, you can send large amount of messages through it. The protocols they use vary but the most standardized applicational protocol is SMPP, through which you can set also sender number/text, how sms is stored in a phone etc.
So you must either get in contact with one network operator or with mediator (usually just reselling same thing). Of course, no operator will give you that for free, usually it is a contract with very low prices for each messsage.